# pythonic way to extract string from this list

Tags: python

if I have a list `['default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static \n', '192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.11 \n']` what will be the most pythonic way to extract `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.0.11` out of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this using regular expressions, where `lst` is the list with the data:

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}[^/]')
[pat.search(s).group(0) for s in lst]
=> ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.11']
```

The above assumes that there's a valid IPv4 IP in each string in the list, and that after the IP there isn't a `/` character.

Comment: This code doesn't give OP the answer he was looking for.  "to extract 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.11 out of it"

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity there you go!

Answer (score 3):

«Most pythonic» might be debatable, but something along these lines will work :

```
fct = lambda e : [w for w in e.split() if '.' in w and '/' not in w][0]
map( fct, l )

> ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.11']
```